# How do I test/fix my USB port from frying whatever gets plugged into it?

Tags: power, usb

I built my PC over 6 years ago, and within the first year the front case USB 2.0 connectors haven't been operable due to frying whatever gets plugged into them. This did not appear to happen until after a few months of putting it together. But then I slowly started discovering that anything I would plug into them would die and I even found evidence that the circuit for the Xbox controller I plugged into it had burned.

I never got around to figuring out how to fix this, but I need to now. There's clearly a short somewhere. I have a multimeter that I could use to test voltage levels out, but really I just need to be able to test the port without destroying whatever it is I plug into it (i.e. I would prefer not to burn through cheap flash drives as my troubleshooting process). If I have the proper troubleshooting procedure, I know I can figure this out.

My electrical knowledge/experience level is barely a pulse. I can't even explain the possibilities as to why this type of shortage may be occurring -- if I could do that, I think I could start exploring possibilities to fix this...

Comment: The only thing that sounds plausible is that you plugged the case panel USB headers into the motherboard incorrectly. Double check that first. Otherwise, with a multimeter you could check that the voltage across pin 1 and pin 4 is +5V. Look up a USB pinout online. You'll probably need a sacrificial USB cable to plug in, cut and strip the wires to get access to the pins, since a typical multimeter probe will not fit inside of a USB connector.

Comment: Rather than stripping a sacrificial cable, would there be a tool that is made for this purpose? Something like this? https://www.amazon.com/Eversame-Multimeter-Chargers-Capacity-Banks-Black/dp/B01D9Y6ZFW/ref=pd_cp_469_1?_encoding=UTF8&refRID=6QWTAZ1B2EYARYF3S8FD&th=1

Comment: @Jon It'd do the trick, but USB cables are cheap and I'm sure you can find a sacrificial one.

Answer (score 3):

I did this same (or similar) thing, once, as a computer tech.  I hadn't realized that the Firewire connections on the motherboard were the same exact spot and looked the same as the USB connections, so I ended up connecting the USB ports to a Firewire connection.

I don't remember the exact results, but it was bad and something ended up getting fried.  #learningexperience

If I was you, besides making sure that the voltages are correct and in the correct pin, make sure that you have the USB port plugged into an actual USB receptacle.  :-)

Comment: I often use the USB port to power 5V equipment (Such as DVI splitters from Kramer). Until now, I've never thought of using 1394 for the same purpose, if i need 12.8 =)

Comment: @Jarmund : That IEEE1394 port ought NOT to be used if you need 12V, because the spec allows a range of 9 to 30V.   Any and all IEEE1394 devices that are plugged in, may become the power source (it isn't a master-slave, but a peer-to-peer interface), which means 'it works today' doesn't guarantee it'll work tomorrow.

Comment: @Whit3rd Most of what I need to power have similar power ratings. rs485->ethernet converters, and the like.

Comment: @Jarmund, as a general rule, it's still not a good idea to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a proper tester, this one costs ten bucks / costs less than a USB thumb drive and will help you confirm it's time to replace those front ports.

I've personally used this one for the past year and it helped me diagnose a faulty Toshiba Satellite and a bad USB hub.

What fries devices more than volts is the AMPs, too many AMPs kills devices and people faster than voltage and trying to slice a USB cable as a multimeter bridge will always leave you wondering ***what if?***

[https://www.amazon.com/PowerJive-Voltage-Multimeter-chargers-capacity/dp/B013FANC9W/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013FANC9W)

[image]

Comment: A device will only draw as many amps as it's designed to take.  Normal power supplies are not designed to "push" amps.  Having a 5 amp PSU doesn't mean it'll push 5 amps at a device, just that it'll have 5 amps available: a device that needs 2 amps will get 2 amps, a 5 amp device will pull 5 amps, and a 12 amp device will not work and potentially damage/destroy the PSU.  Volts will very much destroy a device.  Plugging a 5v device into 9v will more than likely fry the device (experience talking here).  Firewire uses 12v, so plugging in a 5v USB drive will definitely fry the drive.

Comment: I do like the find of the USB power tester!  Even though I'm not a computer tech anymore, I'm still tempted to get one.  Nothing like having gadgets I'm never likely to use.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it is an actual short. A literal short circuit would damage the port itself, while the connected device would simply not power up, but work fine connected to a different PC.

One test you can do is to grab a USB cable that you can sacrifice, and strip it so that you have the four wires (five, if you count the bare ground wire) bare. The red and black pair are the ones supplying power, and these should have 5 volts between them. Any more than that, . The other pair (green and white) is the data bus. If you have a good multimeter, you should have a voltage between these two as well, but as it's a digital signal this will jump between 0 and 5, so depending on your meter, it can read 0, 5, something in between, or something completely different, so troubleshooting this pair is beyond the scope of this answer.

To sum up: Ensure that the red/black pair has 5 volts between them, with red being the positive.

PS: Be sure not to short any of the wires. While many (most?) boards have built in short protection, you don't want to risk frying the bus.

Comment: This assumes the cable uses standard colors, which is not at all guaranteed. The vast majority of cables I've torn apart stray from typical color convention (I've had cables with a +5V white wire and a green COM wire)

Comment: @Shamtam True, I've seen many cables with red, black, white, blue instead. I've also seen some special cases for certain equipment where the data pair was reversed in one end (I think the Vendor just liked selling cables), but speculating non-standard cables and any potential problems related to that is worth an answer in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Check the voltage, with a reliable testing device such as a multimeter or a USB tester. If you use a multimeter, make sure you don't short out the probes on the outside of the usb case (which is connected to shield or ground). Over-voltage would be the main problem. Or if the pins were swapped somehow.

The voltage should read around 5V. Any more than 5.2V and your going to have issues, the protection diodes in the device will turn on and start to heat up (if no diodes exist then it will start to fry the device.) Check the data pins, the voltage should be near zero. If there is 5V on the data pins you will also have problems.

If these ports are soldered directly to the motherboard then you will probably not be able to fix the problem as you will have to reverse engineer the motherboard circuits. If its a chassis usb or usb that plugs into the motherboard, then check the pinout on the motherboard with the pinout of the cable (if you don't know what the pinout of the cable is, set your meter to ohms mode and probe the cable, when the meter shows zero ohms then you know how its connected)

[image]